# Running SSH over Tor?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, tor

I hope this question hasn't been covered already -

I'm trying to run SSH through Tor.  I've followed the instructions at the [tor wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/Misc#SSH) with no success.  I've been using Method 2 with connect.c.  My ssh_config looks like the following:

> Host 192.168.*. *
>
> ProxyCommand none
>
> Host *
>
> ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/connect -4 -S 127.0.0.1:9151 %h %p

I set up an EC2 server and have been able to SSH in successfully with the above settings.  However, when I look at the sshd logs in var/log/auth.log, it shows the following:

> Jul 27 01:10:58 myserver sshd[1587]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for [ISP address] [my.real.ip] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
>
> Jul 27 01:10:58 myserver sshd[1587]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu from [my real ip] port 61358 ssh2
>
> Jul 27 01:10:58 myserver sshd[1587]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)

In other words, my actual IP is shown as making the login request.  Am I totally misunderstanding the purpose of SSH over tor?  Is it possible to run SSH through tor such that the login attempt is shown as coming from a tor exit node?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use torsocks based on [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) [proxifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers) for Tor:

```
# dpkg -l torsocks
ii  torsocks      1.2-3    amd64   use SOCKS-friendly applications with Tor
# torsocks ssh user@server
#Enter a password

# Welcome !

shell:~/$ who
me pts/16       2013-08-31 22:41 (tor2.tedesca.net)
```

I'm from: tor2.tedesca.net